# RDLC item width is dynamic and causing extra pages to be generated (image included)?

Tags: reporting, rdlc, reporting-services

I'm trying to format an RDLC report file in Visual Studio 2008 and I am having a formatting issue. I have a list at the bottom that contains a matrix that expands horizontally to the right. That pink box is just to visualize the problem I'm having.

When the report is rendered the matrix expands and instead of filling the pink box with the matrix is pushes the space in the pink box to the right resulting in an extra page when printing the reports.

One solution would be to shrink the pink box to be the size of the matrix which I've done. But then when the matrix grows the fields at the top of the report get pushed to the right by the same amount as the growth of the matrix.

Can someone please let me know what they think the solution would be? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rectangles, try this http://www.lukehayler.com/2009/07/managing-reporting-services-layouts-using-the-rectangle-in-ssrs/